# SSIS/DTSX/ETL error: "The data in the reparse point buffer is invalid."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, execute-sql-task

I have an SSIS/DTSX/ETL which is giving me the following error in a "Task" in the "Control Flow":

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "Could not retrieve COM class factory for component with CLSID {8957A18C-F62B-4A46-83FC-E8792FFD06DC} debido al siguiente error: 80071128 The data in the reparse point buffer is invalid. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80071128).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

The only thing that this task does is execute an SQL query on a SQL Server DB. To edit that DTSX I use "SQL Server Data Tools 2015". The DTSX was created with VS 2010 Ultimate, I don't know if that has to do with the problem...

[image]

As shown in the image, I am executing the following SQL Command:

```sql
DELETE FROM TBLEMPRESAREPRESENTACION
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you write the code you are executing inside the "Execute SQL Task". HAve you looked at this https://www.howtoedge.com/fix-invalid-reparse-point-buffer-error-0x80071128/ ?

Comment: You can view the code at attached image.

Comment: Hi - one of the rules for this site is that all questions must be in English. If you wish to ask a question in another language then there are other language-specific versions of Stackoverflow available

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not in English

Comment: @NickW I tried to translate the question. But, I think that it should be posted on https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `TargetServerVersion` is correct and set to the current SQL Server installation:

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)